# Colouring components of vector with Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I am struggling with what is probably a simple problem. I want to use the command `Plot3D` to plot the components of a vector (or perhaps a function that returns a list), that I have defined outside `Plot`. When I do this, Mathematica plots each component correctly, but all with one colour. If I define the list of functions inside `Plot` command then I get a different colour for each component. Is there any way to get the second multicoloured behaviour in the first situation? I tried using `ColorFunction`, but this does a colour depending on the height, rather than which component of the list it is in.

Examples

```
g[x_, y_] := {x, y, x y};
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

versus

```
Plot3D[{x, y, x y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution is to use Evaluate. Like so:

```
g[x_, y_] := {x, y, x y}; 
Plot3D[Evaluate @ g[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]